# Developing Bigcommerce Blueprint theme locally

Tags: themes, development-environment, bigcommerce

I can't seem to find any information on developing a Bigcomemrce site, based on the Blueprint theme, locally.

There is plenty of documentation developing their new framework Stencil locally, as well as moving it live, but can't find any info on their base Blueprint theme.

Any help on this and any development workflow tips would be appreciated.

Comment: At the moment there really isn't a way to do true local theme development on Blueprint. You can download the files via WebDAV and edit them locally, but you need to upload the files to BC in order for the theme engine to render the pages. Local development is supported in the upcoming Stencil framework.

Comment: This was of great help. Thank you.

Comment: Sure thing. Happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it isn't possible to develop on Blueprint locally. If you want to see any changes you've made, those files have to be pushed to the Bigcommerce servers through the store's webdav connection. Stencil is built on node.js and thus why it can be developed locally. This is a fundamental difference between Stencil and Blueprint or old template themes.

Comment: Is there any update on this? Is it possible now to run Blueprint locally?

Comment: @Swamy It will never be possibly to run blueprint locally due to how it was built.